# pandas series || get index of string if present

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

Please bear with me. I am new to pandas and using series within it.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["koala", "dog", "chameleon"])
```

`'dog' in s.values` - this allows test if it is present or otherwise.

`s.isin(['dog']).any()`  - this works true. But there isn't any way to get index or use find.

How do I find index/location of "dog"?

Second, if I have duplicate entries (of dog, for e.g.):

```
s = pd.Series(["koala", "dog", "chameleon","dog"])
```

How would I be able to find first or last occurrence?

I am on python 3X (OS X, M1):
`Python 3.9.8 (v3.9.8:bb3fdcfe95, Nov  5 2021, 16:40:46) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[].index` to get the index of a value in a `series`.

```
s = pd.Series(["koala", "dog", "chameleon"])
s[s == 'dog'].index
```

Similarly to get the first and last occurrence using `min()` and `max()`:

```
s = pd.Series(["koala", "dog", "chameleon","dog"])
d_first, d_last = s[s == 'dog'].index.min(), s[s == 'dog'].index.max()
```

Comment: Thank you. I used code as above, however, I do not get index as an integer:  `s[s == 'dog'].index`
`Out[115]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')`

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is:

```
#....in clause like
i = s.index[s.str.contains('dog')]
```

That corresponds to an "in" clause. If you want the correct match you can go of "eq":

```
i2 = s.index[s.eq('dog')]
```

In this case, they produce the same index of course.

Answer (score 2):

Change order of boolean mask for filter `index` and get last value in `next` with `iter`:

```
m = s.eq('dog')[::-1]
#if list
m = s.isin(['dog'])[::-1]

print (next(iter(m.index[m]), 'no match'))
3
```

If always match simplier is use:

```
print (m[m].index[-1])
3
```

Answer (score 2):

To improve on the answer of @sophocles, I found this to give the correct answer.

```
s = pd.Series(["koala", "dog", "chameleon"])
dog_index = s[s == 'dog'].index.values[0]
```